# References that use trace distance to calculate quality of teleportation

Tags: resource-request, teleportation, trace-distance

State fidelity is the most used measure to compute similarity of input and output states in articles dealing with a quantum teleportation.

For my research, I would like to know whether are there references that use trace distance to calculate quality in the teleportation?

Comment: There are methods to convert between bounds on fidelity and trace distance if that helps.

Comment: I would like articles about teleportation that used trace distance instead of fidelity.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just saying that it is possible for you to take an article that used fidelity and convert their results to use the trace-distance.